# Name does not exist error sqlite3 database using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm learning SQLite databases using Python3 following a tutorial and attempting to generate a database using the code below. While attempting to run the code I get an error name 'org' does not exist even thought I create the table using org and count. The original sample code uses email instead of org and if I run the sample code without changing email to org it runs just fine. But as soon as I attempt to change the column name it throws the error I don't understand why I'm getting the error when all I am doing is changing the name of the column. I did delete the database between attempts just in case that was the problem. any incite as to why this is happening would be appreciated.

my code is:

```
    import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('emaildb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if (len(fname) < 1): fname = 'mbox.txt'
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: '): continue
    pieces = line.split()
    email = pieces[1]
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org = ? ', (org, ))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (org, count)
                VALUES (?, 1)''', (org, ))
    else:
        cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE org = ?',(org,))
    conn.commit()

# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
sqlstr = 'SELECT org, count FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'

for row in cur.execute(sqlstr):
    Eprint(str(row[0]), row[1])

cur.close()
```

the original sample is

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('emaildb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (email TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if (len(fname) < 1): fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: '): continue
    pieces = line.split()
    email = pieces[1]
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE email = ? ', (email,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (email, count)
                VALUES (?, 1)''', (email,))
    else:
        cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE email = ?',
                    (email,))
    conn.commit()

# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
sqlstr = 'SELECT email, count FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'

for row in cur.execute(sqlstr):
    print(str(row[0]), row[1])

cur.close()
```

Comment: `DROP TABLE ...` and then `CREATE TABLE...` will create the table as you want it, so double check which code that you are executing.

Comment: theoretically its supposed to drop the table if it already exists then create the new one with those 2 columns but when it his line 18  `cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org = ? ', (org, ))` i get the error name 'org' doesn't exist but it should because its supposed to be created with `cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)''')`

Comment: It is not theoretical. This is what it does.

Comment: I know... Thus my question how can the name not exist if it has infact been created

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible. Is this your actual code? Because as it is the new code does not even run.

Comment: You left `email = pieces[1]` in the new code. Do you mean: `org = pieces[1]`?

Comment: Yep thats the problem completely miss that. I've been pulling my hair out for hours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I miss changing a variable name for `email=pieces[1]` to `org =pieces[1]` thanks for the catch @forpas